# .slideDown Not Working For ME

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I've managed to link my index.html to jquery but for some reason my .slideDown code is not working. Is there something wrong with it or did I not attach jquery correctly?

Here is my html code (containing the code for .slideDown):

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>TEST</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../Pictures/Logo.png" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<script>
$("#teamalpha").mouseover(
function(){
    $("#teamalpha > div").slideDown(400);
    });


</script>
<div id="teamalpha">
<div>
<p>AlphaGuardian</p>
<p>Owner</p>
</div>

</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And Here is my CSS code (stylesheet linked correctly):

```
#teamalpha{


    font-family:Optimus;
    font-size:24px;
    text-align:center;
    border:solid;
    border-color:#000;
    width:250px;
    height:250px;
    position:relative;
    top:100px;
    left:200px;
    cursor:pointer;
    z-index:5;
    }



    #teamalpha div{
    position:relative;
    top:-50px;  
    height:100px;
    display:none;
    width:250;
        background-color:#f7931e;
        z-index:6;
        }
```

Comment: You need to move your jQuery code to the end of the page or put it in a document ready handler.

Comment: as @j08691 says, your code is running before the html elements exist that it is looking for

Comment: put your `js` code in `$(function() { ... });`

Answer (score 1):

Your `<script>` needs to be surrounded by

```
// Fire on document ready event
$(document).ready(function(){
    // some code here
});
```

OR

```
// Fire on window load event 
$(window).load(function() {
    // some code here
});
```

So it should look like this:

```
<script>
// Fire on document ready event
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#teamalpha", this).on("mouseover", function() {
        $(this).children("div").slideDown(400);
    }); 
}); 
</script>
```

OR
    
    // Fire on document ready event
    $(window).load(function() {
        $("#teamalpha", this).on("mouseover", function() {
            $(this).children("div").slideDown(400);
        }); 
    });

Your script was running before the page was fully loaded.  Now, it'll wait till the `document` or the `window` finish loading.

Answer (score 0):

I made a pen with code that worked: http://codepen.io/KK4OXJ/pen/Eagjax/

Basically, you can't fade something in that's hidden with CSS, so we need this: 

`$('#teamalpha div').hide();`

to hide it, instead of using CSS to hide it. It needs to go right before the mousover thing, and we also need to remove the `display: none;` line in the CSS.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Um yeah, he does need the "$(document).ready(...) thing", or the code has to go at the end of the document, as my comment above states.

Comment: Check out my pen, with the $(document).ready(...) commented out, it still works: http://codepen.io/KK4OXJ/pen/Eagjax/

Comment: That's because your codepen places the JavaScript at the end of the page for you.

Comment: Using devtools in debug mode, I moved the script to the very top of the <head>, before anything else. It still works. Try it yourself, and see.

Comment: Your dev tools changes are being made *after* the page has been rendered. See this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/7tqdwbx2/. Doesn't work there does it? Change the loading from the head to onload or body and it works fine.

Comment: OK, I see now. Sorry about that :)